# error: non-static variable scan cannot be referenced from a static context in Java

Tags: java, syntax-error

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CHP4Ex
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.println("enter a n: ");
            int n = scan.nextInt();
            int i=10;
            while (i<n)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
                i = i + 10;
            }
        }
}
```

Why am I getting this error? I'm basically writing a while loop that prints all positive numbers that are divisible by 10 and less than n. For example, if n is 100, enter 10 ... 90.

Comment: You are getting the error because non static variables cannot be accessed from static context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the Scanner class object inside the main function. Basically the problem is that your code violates the static feature. You cannot use non-static members inside a static function, main being static in your case. So it should be :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CHP4Ex
    {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("enter a n: ");
            int n = scan.nextInt();
            int i=10;
            while (i<n)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
                i = i + 10;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Exactly, or make scanner as `static`

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to non static variable in static context, so change

`Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);`

to

`private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);` It should work